# IntelliJ IDEA 14 step in decompiled code?

Tags: java, debugging, intellij-idea, decompiling

With IDEA 14 onwards there is included Java decompiler. This is great  but I cannot step in the decompiled code. If I were to set up break point inside a decompiled function it just stops at the method signature - I cannot go over the code - just stare at it. It even says "Method breakpoints may dramatically slow debugging" or something like that.

So my question is how would I step in the decompiled code ? I am not keen on downloading the source code and compiling it myself - too much hassle.

The reason I need to step in that code is to investigate a NPE being thrown inside a 3rd party library. The error message isn't helpful at all - so I'd like to look under the hood and see what's actually going on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible in 14, but it is possible in 14.1

### [Debug Decompiled Code with IntelliJ IDEA 14.1](http://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2015/02/debug-decompiled-code-with-intellij-idea-14-1/)

Comment: Thanks... but could you suggest any alternative while I wait for 14.1 update? :)

Comment: It is working already - download and use 14.1 :) https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/IDEADEV/IDEA+14.1+EAP